# Developing a heuristic to test simple anonymous Python functions for equivalency

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, bytecode

I know how function comparison works in Python 3 (just comparing address in memory), and I understand why.

I also understand that "true" comparison (do functions `f` and `g` return the same result given the same arguments, for any arguments?) is practically impossible.

I am looking for something in between. I want the comparison to work on the simplest cases of identical functions, and possibly some less trivial ones:

```
lambda x : x == lambda x : x # True
lambda x : 2 * x == lambda y : 2 * y # True
lambda x : 2 * x == lambda x : x * 2 # True or False is fine, but must be stable
lambda x : 2 * x == lambda x : x + x # True or False is fine, but must be stable
```

Note that I'm interested in solving this problem for anonymous functions (`lambda`), but wouldn't mind if the solution also works for named functions.

The motivation for this is that inside `blist` module, it would be nice to verify that two `sortedset` instances have the same sort function before performing a union, etc. on them.

Named functions are of less interest because I can assume them to be different when they are not identical. After all, suppose someone created two sortedsets with a named function in the `key` argument. If they intend these instances to be "compatible" for the purposes of set operations, they'd probably use the same function, rather than two separate named functions that perform identical operations.

I can only think of three approaches. All of them seem hard, so any ideas appreciated.

1. Comparing bytecodes might work but it might be annoying that it's implementation dependent (and hence the code that worked on one Python breaks on another).
2. Comparing tokenized source code seems reasonable and portable. Of course, it's less powerful (since identical functions are more likely to be rejected).
3. A solid heuristic borrowed from some symbolic computation textbook is theoretically the best approach. It might seem too heavy for my purpose, but it actually could be a good fit since lambda functions are usually tiny and so it would run fast.

EDIT

A more complicated example, based on the comment by @delnan:

```
# global variable
fields = ['id', 'name']

def my_function():
  global fields
  s1 = sortedset(key = lambda x : x[fields[0].lower()])
  # some intervening code here
  # ...
  s2 = sortedset(key = lambda x : x[fields[0].lower()])
```

Would I expect the key functions for `s1` and `s2` to evaluate as equal?

If the intervening code contains any function call at all, the value of `fields` may be modified, resulting in different key functions for `s1` and `s2`. Since we clearly won't be doing control flow analysis to solve this problem, it's clear that we have to evaluate these two lambda functions as different, if we are trying to perform this evaluation before runtime. (Even if `fields` wasn't global, it might have been had another name bound to it, etc.) This would severely curtail the usefulness of this whole exercise, since few lambda functions would have no dependence on the environment.

EDIT 2:

I realized it's very important to compare the function objects as they exist in runtime. Without that, all the functions that depend on variables from outer scope cannot be compared; and most useful functions do have such dependencies. Considered in runtime, all functions with the same signature are comparable in a clean, logical way, regardless of what they depend on, whether they are impure, etc.

As a result, I need not just the bytecode but also the global state as of the time the function object was created (presumably `__globals__`). Then I have to match all variables from outer scope to the values from `__globals__`.

Comment: Are you aware, and did you account for the fact, that the meaning of a function object can change drastically depending on what enviroment is closes over? For instance, two function objects created from `lambda: 1/0 if foo else 1` will vary wildly in their behaviour if one closes over `foo = True` and the other closes over `foo = False`. And let's not even think about impure functions and `eval`...

Comment: To address your actual problem, you don't stryctly need what you're asking for. You just care if two lambdas are *sort-equivalent*. How does your data look like? You could just feed them a sample of it, but it's not a 100% reliable. I'd say that the best to solution (to your actual problem) would be a better design.

Comment: @RikPoggi Sorry for the confusion. I just updated the question to clarify that I'm trying to think about the design of the data structure package, `blist`. So sort functions come from outside (from the users of the package).

Comment: @max: Are you saying that the design can't be changed or that there's no better one? For instance the sorting functions could be provided by you, so with the user using only those you'll know which one they choose. Or you could provide a different API set that give you control over the sorting functions. Or... This were just the first things coming to mind, I'm sure there are other (and better) ways, it may be worth to ask for that :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9555/discussion-between-delnan-and-agf)

Comment: My answer should give false positives only when external state is involved, though it may give false negatives when the functions have operations in different orders but the result is unaffected. I also changed it to warn you when external state is involved, so you know that a false-positive is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edited to check whether external state will affect the sorting function as well as if the two functions are equivalent.

---

I hacked up `dis.dis` and friends to output to a global file-like object. I then stripped out line numbers and normalized variable names (without touching constants) and compared the result.

You could clean this up so `dis.dis` and friends `yield`ed out lines so you wouldn't have to trap their output. But this is a working proof-of-concept for using `dis.dis` for function comparison with minimal changes.

```
import types
from opcode import *
_have_code = (types.MethodType, types.FunctionType, types.CodeType,
              types.ClassType, type)

def dis(x):
    """Disassemble classes, methods, functions, or code.

    With no argument, disassemble the last traceback.

    """
    if isinstance(x, types.InstanceType):
        x = x.__class__
    if hasattr(x, 'im_func'):
        x = x.im_func
    if hasattr(x, 'func_code'):
        x = x.func_code
    if hasattr(x, '__dict__'):
        items = x.__dict__.items()
        items.sort()
        for name, x1 in items:
            if isinstance(x1, _have_code):
                print >> out,  "Disassembly of %s:" % name
                try:
                    dis(x1)
                except TypeError, msg:
                    print >> out,  "Sorry:", msg
                print >> out
    elif hasattr(x, 'co_code'):
        disassemble(x)
    elif isinstance(x, str):
        disassemble_string(x)
    else:
        raise TypeError, \
              "don't know how to disassemble %s objects" % \
              type(x).__name__

def disassemble(co, lasti=-1):
    """Disassemble a code object."""
    code = co.co_code
    labels = findlabels(code)
    linestarts = dict(findlinestarts(co))
    n = len(code)
    i = 0
    extended_arg = 0
    free = None
    while i < n:
        c = code[i]
        op = ord(c)
        if i in linestarts:
            if i > 0:
                print >> out
            print >> out,  "%3d" % linestarts[i],
        else:
            print >> out,  '   ',

        if i == lasti: print >> out,  '-->',
        else: print >> out,  '   ',
        if i in labels: print >> out,  '>>',
        else: print >> out,  '  ',
        print >> out,  repr(i).rjust(4),
        print >> out,  opname[op].ljust(20),
        i = i+1
        if op >= HAVE_ARGUMENT:
            oparg = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i+1])*256 + extended_arg
            extended_arg = 0
            i = i+2
            if op == EXTENDED_ARG:
                extended_arg = oparg*65536L
            print >> out,  repr(oparg).rjust(5),
            if op in hasconst:
                print >> out,  '(' + repr(co.co_consts[oparg]) + ')',
            elif op in hasname:
                print >> out,  '(' + co.co_names[oparg] + ')',
            elif op in hasjrel:
                print >> out,  '(to ' + repr(i + oparg) + ')',
            elif op in haslocal:
                print >> out,  '(' + co.co_varnames[oparg] + ')',
            elif op in hascompare:
                print >> out,  '(' + cmp_op[oparg] + ')',
            elif op in hasfree:
                if free is None:
                    free = co.co_cellvars + co.co_freevars
                print >> out,  '(' + free[oparg] + ')',
        print >> out

def disassemble_string(code, lasti=-1, varnames=None, names=None,
                       constants=None):
    labels = findlabels(code)
    n = len(code)
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        c = code[i]
        op = ord(c)
        if i == lasti: print >> out,  '-->',
        else: print >> out,  '   ',
        if i in labels: print >> out,  '>>',
        else: print >> out,  '  ',
        print >> out,  repr(i).rjust(4),
        print >> out,  opname[op].ljust(15),
        i = i+1
        if op >= HAVE_ARGUMENT:
            oparg = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i+1])*256
            i = i+2
            print >> out,  repr(oparg).rjust(5),
            if op in hasconst:
                if constants:
                    print >> out,  '(' + repr(constants[oparg]) + ')',
                else:
                    print >> out,  '(%d)'%oparg,
            elif op in hasname:
                if names is not None:
                    print >> out,  '(' + names[oparg] + ')',
                else:
                    print >> out,  '(%d)'%oparg,
            elif op in hasjrel:
                print >> out,  '(to ' + repr(i + oparg) + ')',
            elif op in haslocal:
                if varnames:
                    print >> out,  '(' + varnames[oparg] + ')',
                else:
                    print >> out,  '(%d)' % oparg,
            elif op in hascompare:
                print >> out,  '(' + cmp_op[oparg] + ')',
        print >> out

def findlabels(code):
    """Detect all offsets in a byte code which are jump targets.

    Return the list of offsets.

    """
    labels = []
    n = len(code)
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        c = code[i]
        op = ord(c)
        i = i+1
        if op >= HAVE_ARGUMENT:
            oparg = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i+1])*256
            i = i+2
            label = -1
            if op in hasjrel:
                label = i+oparg
            elif op in hasjabs:
                label = oparg
            if label >= 0:
                if label not in labels:
                    labels.append(label)
    return labels

def findlinestarts(code):
    """Find the offsets in a byte code which are start of lines in the source.

    Generate pairs (offset, lineno) as described in Python/compile.c.

    """
    byte_increments = [ord(c) for c in code.co_lnotab[0::2]]
    line_increments = [ord(c) for c in code.co_lnotab[1::2]]

    lastlineno = None
    lineno = code.co_firstlineno
    addr = 0
    for byte_incr, line_incr in zip(byte_increments, line_increments):
        if byte_incr:
            if lineno != lastlineno:
                yield (addr, lineno)
                lastlineno = lineno
            addr += byte_incr
        lineno += line_incr
    if lineno != lastlineno:
        yield (addr, lineno)

class FakeFile(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.store = []
    def write(self, data):
        self.store.append(data)

a = lambda x : x
b = lambda x : x # True
c = lambda x : 2 * x
d = lambda y : 2 * y # True
e = lambda x : 2 * x
f = lambda x : x * 2 # True or False is fine, but must be stable
g = lambda x : 2 * x
h = lambda x : x + x # True or False is fine, but must be stable

funcs = a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h

outs = []
for func in funcs:
    out = FakeFile()
    dis(func)
    outs.append(out.store)

import ast

def outfilter(out):
    for i in out:
        if i.strip().isdigit():
            continue
        if '(' in i:
            try:
                ast.literal_eval(i)
            except ValueError:
                i = "(x)"
        yield i

processed_outs = [(out, 'LOAD_GLOBAL' in out or 'LOAD_DECREF' in out)
                            for out in (''.join(outfilter(out)) for out in outs)]

for (out1, polluted1), (out2, polluted2) in zip(processed_outs[::2], processed_outs[1::2]):
    print 'Bytecode Equivalent:', out1 == out2, '\nPolluted by state:', polluted1 or polluted2
```

The output is `True`, `True`, `False`, and `False` and is stable. The "Polluted" bool is true if the output will depend on external state -- either global state or a closure.

Comment: Very cool.. I'm still trying to work through the code, and figure out how to port it to Python 3. One thing I noticed is that the bytecode comparison says that LOAD_GLOBAL 0 (x) is the same as LOAD_GLOBAL 0 (y); I assume it's ok to change that to evaluate as non-equal?

Comment: @max Do you want two functions that differ only by what they call their arguments to be different? Your example specifically stated you wanted those to compare equal -- `lambda x: 2 * x` and `lambda y: 2 * y`. That is the reason for replacing all variable names with `x`. As long as all the other operations are the same, the names of the variables seem irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, but there's a difference between variables that are parameters for lambda and variables that are from outer scope. The former can be renamed without impact; the latter can't.

Comment: @max Ah, I see what you mean. Makes sense. After work maybe I'll see about switching it to parsing into a list of dictionaries, one per line, and what to ignore can be a separate, tunable step.

Comment: Also, as far as porting to Python 3, where I changed `print ...` to `print >>out, ...` you just change `print(...)` to `print(..., file = out)`. That's really the only change I made to the `dis` functions.

Answer (score 6):

So, let's address some technical issues first.

1) Byte code: it is probably not an problem because, instead of inspecting the pyc (the binary files), you can use `dis` module to get the "bytecode". e.g.

```
>>> f = lambda x, y : x+y
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

No need to worry about platform.

2) Tokenized source code. Again python has all you need to do the job. You can use the `ast` module to parse the code and obtain the ast.

```
>>> a = ast.parse("f = lambda x, y : x+y")
>>> ast.dump(a)
"Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='f', ctx=Store())], value=Lambda(args=arguments(args=[Name(id='x', ctx=Param()), Name(id='y', ctx=Param())], vararg=None, kwarg=None, defaults=[]), body=BinOp(left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), op=Add(), right=Name(id='y', ctx=Load()))))])"
```

So, the question we should really address is: is it feasible to determine that two functions are equivalent **analytically**?

It is easy for human to say `2*x` equals to `x+x`, but how can we create an algorithm to prove it?

If it is what you want to achieve, you may want to check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_proof

However, if ultimately you simply want to assert two different data set are sorted in the same order, you just need to run the sort function A on dataset B and vice versa, and then check the outcome. If they are identical, then the functions are probably functionally identical. Of course, the check is only valid for the said datasets.

Comment: Your last point -- the only reason to use `blist` in the first place is performance, and you destroy that if you have to run twice as many sorts. AST -- will he always have access to the source objects? Com. ass't proof -- while the idea is interesting, a proof of possibility doesn't give you a practical method, and there could be an adequate heuristic even if you can prove that it is impossible in the general case (which it almost certainly is). Bytecode / Dis - Yes, as I demonstrated in my answer, this works if you capture output, strip line numbers, and normalize variable names.

Comment: Point taken. I wasn't sure how sophisticated you want the comparison to be. If the sort functions are written in a rather uniform way, comparison should do really.

Comment: The resulting bytecode might be different between Python interpreters, leading to different behavior of the comparison. And I just realized another problem with bytecode: it doesn't distinguish `lambda` arguments from names from outer scope. I would need to do more work on it if I wanted to use it. The more I think about it, the less reason I have to compare 2*x as equal to x+x; for my purposes, it seems clear that if the programmer compares sortedsets with such two sort keys, it's probably by mistake.